# Build data frame from multiple rvest elements

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to do some web scraping of journal article metadata (title, authors, abstract, etc.). I have a list of pages that I need to navigate and each page has the information that I need (except for the table of contents pages that are in my list). I built a function to piece together each part of the page into a list and I'm trying to go through each page and end up with a data frame of my results.

Here is what I have:

```
article.links <- c("http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20116/abstract", 
"http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20120/abstract", 
"http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20117/abstract"
)

pager <- function(page) {
  new.row = vector("list", 4)
  page <- read_html(page)

  #DOI
  new.row[1] <- page %>%
    html_node("#doi") %>%
    html_text()

  #Title
  new.row[2] <- page %>%
    html_node(".mainTitle") %>%
    html_text()

  #Authors
  new.row[3] <- page %>%
    html_node("#authors") %>%
    html_text()

  #Abstract
  new.row[4] <- page %>%
    html_node("#abstract") %>%
    html_text()

  return(unlist(new.row))
}
```

When I run `pager.test(article.links.test[1])` the results are what I would expect for 1 entry. I'm not quite sure what to do to build a data frame with the series of results though. I tried a for loop with rbind to put the rows together but when I try all of the rows it throws errors about the entries being generated:

```
#This is what doesn't seem to work
abstracts <- data.frame()
for(key in 1:length(article.links.test)) {
  abstracts <- rbind(abstracts2, pager.test(article.links.test[key]))
}
```

How can I scrape elements from each of the pages in my list and combine the results as a data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `lapply` and then `rbind` the rows

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
library(rvest)
article.links <- c("http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20116/abstract",                     
    "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20120/abstract", 
    "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jee.20117/abstract"
)

pager <- function(page) {
    doc <- read_html(url(page))
    data.frame(DOI=doc %>% html_node("#doi") %>% html_text(),
        Title=doc %>% html_node(".mainTitle") %>% html_text(),
        Authors=doc %>% html_node("#authors") %>% html_text(),
        Abstract=doc %>% html_node("#abstract") %>% html_text())
}

ans <- do.call(rbind, lapply(article.links, pager))
str(ans)
```